# Will the time spent for context switch be counted into some process's system-cpu-time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

Generally, %Sys stands for the amount of CPU time spent in the kernel within the process. It consists of time spent for things like allocating memory or accessing hardware (HDD, network, etc.) This is easy to understand since these works are done by kernel on behalf of the given process.

However, when things come to context-switch, it's not so intuitive anymore. Since context switch is not something "requested by a given process and done by the kernel", I wonder which process's quota would the context-switching time will be counted into.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise with the terminology, "context switching" simply means switching from user to kernel space and vice-versa. For example, performing a syscall implies context switching, so context switching is very often requested by processes.

As per *involuntary* context switches (preemption), such as hardware and software interrupts, by default Linux accounts the time spent in those to the currently running task. If the kernel is configured with [`CONFIG_IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING=y`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING.html), then interrupt handling time is not accounted to the current task, at the cost of a small performance hit.